# Razor 2 View Relative content not rendering from specific folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm unsure if this is a bug with MVC4, or whether it's some configuration somewhere.

I have an MVC4 (ASP.NET 4.5, C#) project. When I have content in the folder `~/Content/images/ads/myimage.jpg` it doesn't render.  In fact, if I use the in-line syntax the resulting html tag is completely removed.

The paths used below are all correct & content is present in the directories specified.

**Razor View:**

```
<img src="~/Content/images/myimage.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="~/Content/images/ads/myimage.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="~/Content/images/lalala/myimage.jpg" alt="" />
```

**Rendered Output on page:**

```
<img src="/Content/images/myimage.jpg" alt="">
<img src="/Content/images/lalala/myimage.jpg" alt="">
```

Is `/Content/images/ads/` a *special* folder?

Answer (score 1):

Mike,

I tried a test project and this is indeed odd. Looking in firebug, you end up with an element formed as such:

```
<img alt="" src="/Content/images/ads/plus.png" class="cmzgzdznkmcoiqvrkgcr">
```

this css rule is defined as:

```
.cmzgzdznkmcoiqvrkgcr {
    -moz-binding: url("chrome://global/content/bindings/general.xml#foobarbazdummy") !important;
}
```

therefore, mvc4 is obviously looking at the /ads/ as a special marker and adding that class. I'll report back later with an edit, should I find the reason why!

Comment: Thanks Jim, I was testing only in chrome and didn't see this at all.